# How to use msgpack in xcode project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, static-libraries, msgpack

I installed msgpack with brew and can compile the sample code with `gcc msgpacktest.c -lmsgpack` in the command line. But when I add the header in `test.m`, a class in my iOS project and add `-lmsgpack` in Compile Sources of Build Phases, I still get the error `msgpack.h file not found`. I am a new programmer and this is confusing me. What am I missing?

Comment: are you building it for iPhone simulator or iOS device?

Comment: I am using the iPhone simulator.

Comment: try to build it for iOS device dude . Because some framework doesn't link for iPhone simulator

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell Xcode where to find the header.  In Build Settings, under Search Paths, add the path under User Header Search Paths.

Comment: I now add /usr/local/Cellar/msgpack/0.5.7 to my Header Search Paths, but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Did you add it under Header Search Paths, or User Header Search Paths?  Try setting Always Search User Paths to YES.  Also, sometimes things don't take effect until you quit and restart Xcode.